# Do I Codesign with Two Certs on OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

On OSX Cocoa application development, do I codesign with two certs or one? (Note, I'm not planning on distributing my app in the Apple AppStore, but from a website.) See, Apple says I need an organizational developer ID to sign my OSX app. Okay, fine, but Chrome and IE browsers like those expensive Symantec EV codesigning certs, at least for Windows apps, more so than other less-expensive EV codesigning certs. (Our tests have shown we get approved by Chrome and IE only with the expensive Symantec EV certs, not the cheaper ones, if wanting to distribute our applications from a website.

So, if indeed I need to code sign with two certs, can you explain the command line process for installing these? Also, note that my application is a little odd and I need to know which items I must codesign. See, in my application, I have:

- The setup app is a compiled, custom .app with a binary inside that loads the GUI. I assume I have to codesign both?
- The application it installs is a GUI-based .app (Cocoa app) that also contains a couple console executables inside the Resources folder. I assume that I have to codesign the .app and the console executables too?

Comment: The cert you use for code signing is different from the cert you use for your web site. You get your code signing certs from Apple and OS X itself will verify the app was signed by a cert it recognizes before running it.

Comment: @Aaron well, yes, I'm quite aware of the SSL on the website. However, in the Windows world, we have to use an expensive Symantec EV codesigning cert on the setup and application in order to get it past the web browser filters on the download -- a lesser cert in our tests shows that it doesn't work and we remain blocked. So, on the Mac, I'm thinking, well, we need an EV cert there, too, I suppose. But then Apple is telling us we need their cert to install on OSX. Confusing because that's two certs.

Comment: I've used Chrome, Safari and Firefox on OS X to download binaries on the Mac and this has never posed a problem. OS X's Gatekeeper is really all you need for distributing on the web.

Comment: @Aaron Okay, so then that's a positive development. I'd rather pay $99 than pay for the expensive Symantec EV cert. I'm also not certain it's even possible to code sign with two separate certs, anyway.

Comment: @Aaron if you reform that into an answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certs that Symantec is offering for your web site are probably quite helpful if you were distributing a Windows app, but Apple has developed a solution of its own in Gatekeeper which I strongly recommend using.

As long as you code sign the app with Gatekeeper when you build it with Xcode, you can distribute it on the web and just about any Mac will be able to open it without issue, regardless of browser they're using.